# moodle 2.7 filemanager issue

Tags: moodle, file-manager

I'm working with a file manager on a form in `moodle 2.7`.

The save and upload files features are fine.

I need to determine if the file manager object currently holds a file.

This is what I've tried:

```
if($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments')){ 
   $A=1; 
}else{ 
   $A=2; 
}
```

But it always return 1;

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
Just after saveing the form files and before update record I use:

```
$fs = get_file_storage();
$files = $fs->get_area_files($context->id, $component,$path, $itemid,'',false);
if(!empty($files){
 $A=1;//have files
}else{
 $A=2;//No files
}
```

this work for me.

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
$draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments')
```

Sets `$draftitemid` to the value returned by `file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments')`. Setting a variable always evaluates to `true` when in an `if` statement. Thus, this is a typo and what you want is:

```
if($draftitemid == file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments')){
```